# Symfony 2 | Sonata | user-bundle : route "admin_sonata_user_user_create" does not exist

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I followed Sonata user-bundle tuto :
http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-2/doc/reference/installation.html

Everything works, I get my Application\Sonata\UserBundle.
I created a super-admin user, i log and on admin/dashboard, i get this error :

```
    An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for
    the named route "admin_sonata_user_user_create" as such route does not exist.") in 
    SonataAdminBundle:Block:block_admin_list.html.twig at line 38.
```

I already installed Sonata months ago and I never get this error, I don't know where I failed and I can't find solutions about this.

This is my config.yml :

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        # path:     "%database_path%"
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
                    SonataUserBundle: ~
                    FOSUserBundle: ~

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

sonata_intl:
    timezone:
        default: Europe/Paris
        detectors:
            - sonata.intl.timezone_detector.user
            - sonata.intl.timezone_detector.locale
        locales:
            fr:    Europe/Paris
            en_UK: Europe/London

sonata_user:
    security_acl: true
    manager_type: orm # can be orm or mongodb

sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
        sonata.user.block.menu:    # used to display the menu in profile pages
        sonata.user.block.account: # used to display menu option (login option)
        sonata.admin.block.search_result:
            contexts: [admin]

# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # [...]
    acl:
        connection: default

fos_user:
    db_driver:      orm # can be orm or odm
    firewall_name:  main
    user_class:     Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User


    group:
        group_class:   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager

    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager
```

If you have any idea where this problem may be (config, installation etc.).
TY very much ;)

Comment: Have you imported routing for sonata user bundle in your main routing.yml ?

Comment: Yes I did, I have admin / sonata_user_security / sonata_user_resetting / sonata_user_profile / sonata_user_register / sonata_user_change_password and sonata_user in my main routing.yml. Everything is like sonata user-bundle tuto.

Comment: I reinstall Sonata and his bundles (admin and user-bundle) but I still get this error ...

Comment: I finally found my error, I failed in Sonata installation. If you have this mistake, retry Sonata installation and be careful with config.yml and security.yml, do not overwrite code by copying and pasting.

Comment: @sAr Can you be a little more specific when you say "I failed Sonata installation"?? What steps did you redo exactly? Update your question with those!

Answer (score 15):

From document at https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/getting_started/installation.html:

Try to put below code in your routing.yml file

```html
_sonata_admin:
  resource: .
  type: sonata_admin
  prefix: /admin
```

Comment: Great, helped me too! But can you please explain what does this mean. What's the trick?

Comment: It's SonataAdminBundle route [related documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/getting_started.html)